# Subir un proyecto a 000webhost

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, necesito aclaraciones para subir mi proyecto de laravel a la web a traves de 000webhost.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que tengo que subir mi proyecto a `public_html`, pero solo he encontrado opción para subir ficheros individuales, no la carpeta entera.
¿Debo quizas comprimir mi proyecto?

Lo que si es que tengo filezilla, y ya he conseguido que se conecte al host:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque es temporal y al cabo de un tiempo se cierra, ademas de que al cerrar y volver a abrir debo volver a introducir los datos del host. ¿Como hago para que la conexión sea de duración indefinida?

Actualizo: Ya he creado un zip de mi proyecto y lo he subido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la historia es que no se que debo hacer a partir de aqui. ¿Ya puedo buscar la pagina web de mi proyecto?

Comment: Creo que el tema la duración de la conexión no lo puedes controlar tu, es parte de la configuracion del servidor

Answer (score 0):

Si comprimes la carpeta y la subes como un fichero `zip` a través de la web podrás subir la carpeta directamente.
En cuanto a la conexión, tanto con `filezilla` como desde la propia web tiene muchos errores de desconexión y vas a tener que ir actualizando la página.

Comment: El problema de compirmir y subir todo de golpe, es que si hay un fallo tienes que empezar desde 0 a subir todo de nuevo. De la otra forma es más progresivo y si has subido 3 ficheros de 10 y te falla, solo tienes que subir 7.

Comment: Así he hecho, he comprimido en un zip mi proyecto y lo he subido. Ahora la historia es a ver que hago a partir de este punto.